# Remove chosen value of django-autocomplete using script

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

I have assigned a value to the `foreign key` element (which is an autocomplete in the form) using `initial`. Coming to the front-end if the category is changed I used script to hide and show fields accordingly. So if I change the category and the auto-complete goes to hidden state I just want to remove its initial value.

I tried this:

```
...
$('#id_category').change(function(){
    var category = $('#id_category').val();

    if(category == 'customer'){
        $('#id_customer').show();
        ...
    } 
    else {
        $('#id_customer').val('').hide();
        ...
    }
});
```

any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#product option').val(null).trigger('change');
```

or
You can use the close button.To remove the value.
This can only used for Customised Autocomplete.[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx1mu.png)

```
$("span.select2-selection__clear").trigger('mousedown');
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I tried a lot of ways to trigger the x button but not worked, can you explain more?

Comment: You can change it in 2 other methods, this one worked for me in that project. Now I am using `remove()` function. like `$('#product option').remove();` It will automatically remove the selected one. `$('#product option').val(null).trigger('change');` can also be used.

Comment: Some versions don't have a close 'x' button in that case you can use the script from the above comment.